# ingress not able to access domain based routing

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am not able to access the domain to running ingress service in the Kubernetes, below is the YAML configuration for the ingress service, I am not able to access **ticketing.dev** in the browser

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
    name: ingress-service
    annotations:
      kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
      nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
    - host: ticketing.dev
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I have added the domain name to the windows host files
driver **\etc\host**
**127.0.0.1 ticketing.dev**

Comment: How is your ingress controller setup? Are you sure it is on ip 127.0.0.1?

Comment: @ssc327, Did not understand what ingress controller setup means, I am not using a custom ingress controller, using the default Kubernetes
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps

Comment: Hello @RahulGupta. What exactly do you mean by "not able to access"? What is the error message and how do you test it?

Comment: Hi @WytrzymałyWiktor, Not able to access it is not loading This site can't be reached ticketing.dev, ingress-controller is also in place with host ticketing.dev I have added the domain name to the host file. it seems it is not exposed outside the Kubernetes cluster, is there any configuration I am missing in the ingress service?

Comment: Are you using minikube? What command did you use to enable ingress?

Comment: Ingress setup has two parts. First you setup the controller on your cluster which will allow traffic in. Then you setup the individual ingress resources that route to a specific service

Comment: @ssc327, I am not using minikube and have used kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.47.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml to enable ingress



from resource 
https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#provider-specific-steps